# Cross Compiling libfreefare-pcsc Error

Tags: cross-compiling, yocto

I am trying to cross-compile libfreefare-pcsc for arm.
I am using the yocto-project to do that and I have a recipe for it.However, the configure script doesn't complete.It fails with error "unable to locate libnfc"
How do I define the path to my libnfc in the configuration?

Here is the log:

```
`DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
DEBUG: Executing shell function autotools_preconfigure
DEBUG: Shell function autotools_preconfigure finished
DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_copy_aclocals
DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
DEBUG: Python function autotools_copy_aclocals finished
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/data3/src/git/Jethro_MobiTill/poky/MobiTill/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/data3/src/git/Jethro_MobiTill/poky/MobiTill/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
libnfc install dir: /libnfc
libnfc include dir found:  /home/data3/src/git/Jethro_MobiTill/poky/MobiTill/tmp/sysroots/cubieboard2/usr/include
libnfc library found:  LIBNFC_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at /home/data3/src/git/Jethro_MobiTill/poky/MobiTill/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find LIBNFC (missing: LIBNFC_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/data3/src/git/Jethro_MobiTill/poky/MobiTill/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindLIBNFC.cmake:17 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/data3/src/git/Jethro_MobiTill/poky/MobiTill/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libfreefare-pcsc/1.0-r0/libfreefare-pcsc-1.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/data3/src/git/Jethro_MobiTill/poky/MobiTill/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libfreefare-pcsc/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.17650)`
```

Comment: Apparently, your library depends on libnfc, which you need to write a recipe for and compile.

Comment: btw, consider copy pasting log  instead of linking to screenshots next time ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @OleksandrKravchuk, I have a recipe for libnfc and it's already built and tested.Will paste a log

Comment: see the log in the original post.

Comment: it seems to not being able to find the package; try to set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH manually

Comment: Any help on how to do that?

Comment: how to do what? use CMAKE_MODULE_PATH()? it's in the cmake docs.